# Android gradle build failed with an exception when include firebase and gms service

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-messaging

I just created an empty android project while including the dependencies I need for the project I got an error only when I add `com.google.firebase` or `com.google.android.gms` it will generate error below.

> /Users/macbookair/Desktop/ANDROID/APPTEST/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>   Error:    Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-21:19 to override.

Please can anyone help me out, I have be trying for very long time to fix this error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fexample.android.appz"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.13.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.41.0'

     //If I uncomment the below line it will trigger error
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'

}
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android { sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/public'] } } }
```

From the below screenshot this `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` also has an error but when I build apk it create successfully, I don't think is good.

> Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not
>   be combined but found
>   IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support',
>   myArtifactId='support-fragment', myVersion='28.0.0', myPacking='aar',
>   myClassifier='null'} and
>   IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.swiperefreshlayout',
>   myArtifactId='swiperefreshlayout', myVersion='1.0.0', myPacking='aar',
>   myClassifier='null'}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest you try one of the following:

1) Migrate the whole project to use the `androidx` libraries which you can do under **Refactor** > **Migrate to AndroidX** from the menu bar.

2) Downgrade the versions of `com.google.firebase` and `com.google.android.gms` from 17.x.x to a lower version

Comment: I just tried the downgrade and it worked but the error here `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` is the there

Comment: Awesome, now i'll advise you migrate the whole project to use the `androidx` libraries like I suggested above

Comment: Okay, by doing this migration will it affect supported device? Because am creating this new test project to see why supported device was dropped in my existing project when I upload the apk and to make a clean project too

Comment: No, the migration won't affect supported devices.

Comment: Sorry that I delayed,    `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'` now it worked so should I go ahead and upgrade those to new version?

Comment: Wow, now the latest version of firebase is working very fine. I appreciate the help

Comment: Please can I make a question about this so you can help me out or any tip on what to do? `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199618/discussion-between-mayokun-and-peter).